# C++ removing punctuation from a map

Tags: c++

I made a program that reads a text document, puts it into a vector, and use said vector for a map to keep track of the words and their frequencies in the text file. All of that is working fine, but need help with removing the punctuation from the map. Here's what I have right now:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

void print_frequency(vector<string>&);


int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    string word;
    vector<string>words;
    infile.open("words.txt");
    if (infile.fail()) {
        cerr << "Can't open file\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    while (infile >> word) {
        
        words.push_back(word);
    }
    
    print_frequency(words);
}

void print_frequency(vector<string>&words)
{
    map<string, int>M;
    for (int i = 0; i<words.size(); i++) {
        if (M.find(words[i]) == M.end())
            M[words[i]] = 1;
        else
            M[words[i]]++;
        
    }
    sort(words.begin(), words.end());
    for (auto it = M.begin(); it != M.end();it++) {
        
        if (ispunct(M[it->first]))
        {
            M[it->first].erase(it--, 1);
            int len = M.size();
        }
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The code is needlessly complex (and inefficient) `for (int i = 0; i<words.size(); i++) M[words[i]]++;` works just as well because `M[words[i]]` will add the word with a count of zero if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to remove the punctuation before you add the strings to the map?

Answer (score 1):

As other said the best idea seems to drop these characters right after reading. For that I would go for `std::regex` library:

```
while (infile >> word) {
    std::string new_word = std::regex_replace(word, std::regex(R"([^A-Za-z\d])"), "");
    words.push_back(new_word);
}
```

`"([^A-Za-z\d])"` means a pattern which is not (`^`) a letter (`A-Za-z`) and not a digit (`\d`). Of course you can modify it to adjust to your strict needs, I encourage to familiarize yourself with the regular expressions syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, probably should've removed the punctuation ASAP otherwise it gets needlessly complicated later on. I was able to get it to work.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

void print_frequency(vector<string>&);


int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    string word;
    vector<string>words;
    infile.open("words.txt");
    if (infile.fail()) {
        cerr << "Can't open file\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    while (infile >> word) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
        {
            if (ispunct(word[i]))
            {
                word.erase(i--, 1);
                
            }
        }
        words.push_back(word);
    }
    
    print_frequency(words);
}

void print_frequency(vector<string>&words)
{
    map<string, int>M;
    for (int i = 0; i<words.size(); i++) {
        if (M.find(words[i]) == M.end())
            M[words[i]] = 1;
        else
            M[words[i]]++;
        
    }
    sort(words.begin(), words.end());
    for (auto it = M.begin(); it != M.end();it++) {
        
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
    }
    
}
```